# Binary tree insert()

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to fill a binary tree with letters which will then be used to encode a Morse code sequence but I am stuck on my insert() method its adding a letter twice or more.

If the code has a '.' it will go left
If the code has '-' it will go right

And then I am trying to traverse it, but my output is showing me lots of the same letter

Here is my `insert()`:

```
private void insert(BinaryNode localRoot, BinaryNode node){
    if (localRoot == null) { //Replace empty tree with new tree with the item at the root.
        localRoot = node;
        return;
    }

    String result = node.getData().toString();//getting Item from BinaryNode.java


    //looping over morse code
    for(int cnt = 0;cnt<result.length();cnt++){

        if(result.charAt(cnt)=='.')
        {
            if (localRoot.getLeftSubtree() == null){
                localRoot.setLeftSubtree(node);}
        }

        else if(result.charAt(cnt)=='-'){

            if (localRoot.getRightSubtree() == null)
                localRoot.setRightSubtree(node);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: To answer this effectively, we need to know what implementation of BinaryNode you are using or see the code for it if it is not publicly available.

Comment: Can we see your traverse method?

Comment: I have added the traverse method at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert method is looping over the whole node string.  When it finds a '.' it adds to the left.  When it finds a '-' it adds to the right.  If your node string has both '.' and '-' in it, it will be added to the left and the right (if the left and right were null to start with).  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it's possible you should only be checking the first letter in your node string.

Comment: I need it to check every letter in the node string because if it is for example 'V' "...-" it will be inserted in the tree at node left>left>left>right

Comment: Well, then only insert it after you've figured out where it really goes -- you're adding it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a tree? Why not use a hashmap?

Comment: A tree seems like the wrong data structure for what you described above. Generally, trees are good for searching an unknown number of entities. In this case, there are a finite number of letters and Morse code sequences. Using a hashmap would give you O(1) lookup time rather than O(ln).

Comment: calculating the hashcode of a string takes O(strlen). So unless you insert or lookup non-interned strings there is no difference in terms of O notation.

Comment: @subsub: iterating over the characters in the string is a wash for both methods. I'm referring to the comparison between the 2 approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` does the following:

If localroot is null, do nothing (well you set two local variables to be the same, but overall that is a no-op)
If your localroot is not null, you set its left subtree to node, for every '.' you find and the right subtree for every '-' you find.

I don't know what your initial "localroot" is, but assuming its an (non null) node representing the empty morse-string, after inserting "A", i.e., ".-", your root will have two children "A" and "A" (the same node object), and will then be replaced by "B", then by "C", "D" and then by "E", which will only set the left subtree...